# accumulation of a value interval with a given operator

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to write a function which accumulates the value interval with the given operator and adds the initial value. Example:

(accumulate-interval + 0 2 4) :
2 + 3 + 4 + 0 = 9

(accumulate-interval * 1 2 5) : 
2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 1 = 120

Note: Only (+) and (*) to work is enough for me.

My code is:

```
(define accumulate-interval
  (lambda (op init lower upper) (if (= upper lower)
   (lambda (x) (op x init))
    (lambda (x)
      (op
      ((accumulate-interval op init lower (- upper 1)) x))))     ))
```

It returns a procedure instead of a value.
I'd really appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a function because that is what you are returning.  **lambda** is a function which creates an anonymous function and returns a reference to it.  When your code does

```
(define accumulate-interval (lambda (op init lower upper) ......))
```

It is using **lambda** to create an anonymous function, return the reference to it and assign that reference as the value of **accumulate-interval**.  **accumulate-interval** is thus associated with that function and that function is run whenever **accumulate-interval** is evaluated in the **function** position in a list.

Now, your **accumulate-interval** function consists of a single **if** expression which does

```
(if (= upper lower) (lambda (x) ...) (lambda (x) ...))
```

So if **upper** and **lower** are equal, it returns a reference to one anonymous function, otherwise it returns a different one.  This is what you have told it to do.

I don't know what you are trying to do, here, but I suspect you just want to execute the code which you are mistakenly wrapping in a function and returning.  So I think your code is meant to look more like

```
(if (= upper lower)
  (op upper init) (op lower (accumulate-interval op init (+ lower 1) upper)))
```

Which should work, although I think you need to rethink your arguments because that recursive call is not in tail position.

Thinking about it,

```
(if (= upper lower)
   (op upper init)
   (accumulate-interval (op upper init) lower (- upper 1)))
```

Would work *and* be tail-recursive.

Note: I don't normally do people's homework for them, but I think you may have more than one misconception about Scheme syntax and showing working code was easier than exploring each of those possible misunderstandings separately and in combination.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of conceptual problems in your code. I agree with @itsbruce, it's simpler to point you in the way of a correct solution than to fix each of the errors found in the question.

First of all, notice that the procedure can be written in terms of existing higher-order functions: `foldr` for accumulating the values and `build-list` for creating the range of values:

```
(define (accumulate-interval op init lower upper)
  (foldr op init
         (build-list (add1 (- upper lower))
                     (lambda (x) (+ lower x)))))
```

Alternatively, in Racket you can use `for/list` for creating the range of values:

```
(define (accumulate-interval op init lower upper)
  (foldr op init
         (for/list ([n (in-range lower (add1 upper))]) n)))
```

If the solution needs to be written from scratch (that's probably the case), it's a good idea to split the problem in parts. First, generate the range of numbers:

```
(define (range lower upper)
  (if (> lower upper)
      '()
      (cons lower
            (range (add1 lower) upper))))
```

Now, accumulate the values:

```
(define (accumulate op init lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      init
      (op (car lst)
          (accumulate op init (cdr lst)))))
```

Finally, combine the two previous helper procedures into a solution to the problem. Notice that in the first two solutions we did exactly the same problem decomposition (first: generate range; second: accumulate; third: combine), the only difference is that here we wrote the helper procedures by hand instead of using already existing procedures:

```
(define (accumulate-interval op init lower upper)
  (accumulate op init
              (range lower upper)))
```

Of course, you could merge all the procedures in one as in your solution - it's more efficient, because it doesn't create an intermediate list of numbers:

```
(define (accumulate-interval op init lower upper)
  (if (> lower upper)
      init
      (op lower
          (accumulate-interval op init (add1 lower) upper))))
```

...But doing so produces a tailor-made solution for just one particular problem, instead of a set of composable procedures useful in other contexts. In functional programming style, it's preferred to define generic, reusable functions.

Anyway, this works as expected:

```
(accumulate-interval + 0 2 4)
> 9

(accumulate-interval * 1 2 5)
> 120
```

Comment: Going to quibble, Oscar ;) You've made the **accumulate** call tail recursive, which is better, but your range function isn't tail recursive, you have two separate recursions for one result and you create a potentially large data object (the range list) where none would be needed if a single recursion were used.

Comment: @itsbruce Actually, neither of my helper procedures is tail recursive. I did this on purpose: first, they're easier to understand for a newbie and second, they preserve operator left-to-right order in case that matters (for example, when accumulating with `-` or `/`)

Comment: I see that, but I really don't think the dual recursion and the need to store an arbitrarily long list is a good example.  It's particularly ironic given your use of fold as an example, at the beginning.

Comment: It's a good example when you're starting with the language. And `foldr` is _not_ tail recursive, for the same reason: I intend to preserve operator left-to-right ordering

Comment: But the OP *nearly* has the recursion right.  Only the lambda misunderstanding prevented him getting it right.  You've added a whole extra piece of misdirection.